# Para aprender C++ é necessário aprender C?

Tags: c, c++

Caso eu queira aprender sobre C++ é necessário eu aprender C antes ou são coisa distintas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não. De certa forma é até recomendável que não aprenda C. Até pode, mas isso pode te confundir. Se decidiu ir para o C++, vá nele. A maioria dos excelentes programadores de C++ admitem que não sabem C.

Há um mito que o C++ é o C "melhorado", mas isso não é verdade. C++ começou sendo uma evolução do C, mas tantas características novas foram colocadas que virou outra linguagem. Embora C++ compile **quase** todos os códigos C, não é assim que se deve programar em C++. Se você programar em C++ de verdade o código é muito diferente do código em C.

E aí tem que tomar cuidado com o material que escolherá para aprender porque muitos ensinam C em C++, ou seja, você nem sabe que estão te enganando, porque funciona, mas não está certo, aí aprende assim:

[image: Fiat 147 bagaçado andando pelas ruas]

C++ é uma linguagem de alto nível com melhores abstrações de custo zero e que está evoluindo muito. C é considerado um Assembly portável, e até por isso quase não evolui e quase não tem abstrações.

Meu sonho de consumo é que o C++ tenha um modo que desligue a possibilidade de usar recursos de C.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Há um mito que o C++ é o C "melhorado", mas isto não é verdade. C++ começou sendo uma evolução do C". Então o quis dizer é que já foi realmente uma evolução do C, porém hoje já é independente? Me veio a dúvida pois já escutei várias vezes essa frase também.

Comment: Pode ter sido inicialmente esta ideia, mas logo se viu que ela teria que ser outra linguagem, como eu disse, há esse mito de que C++ é o C evoluído. Como em muitas coisas, mas muitas mesmo, na computação alguém ensina errado, e isso se espalha tanto que as pessoas deixam de aprender o certo. E pior, quando alguém fala o certo ninguém acredita porque está quase todo mundo falando o errado, então as pessoas acham que isto é o certo. É *fake news* para todo o lado.

Comment: Isso realmente é verdade, inclusive vc já desmitificou uma dessas fake news pra mim em relação ao switch. De tanto que falam uma mentira a mentira acaba se tornando a verdade pra maioria. Mas obrigado por responder.